# How do I actualize the visible files in File Explorer on Windows browsing SDCard of Sony Xperia Ray?

Tags: files

If I browse my SDcard on Windows 7 I can see only the folders that where there the first time I connected the phone via USB.

When I create a new folder on the device later, It is not visible in the Windows Explorer.

these are the steps to reproduce:

1. connect the phone via usb to Windows
2. open the sdcard in windows explorer
3. use ES File Explorer to create a new folder on the sdcard

now the new folder is not visible in Windows. Even a refresh with F5 doesent make it visible in Windows.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How does the topic match your post? What are you trying to delete/modify? Can you give an example path? You won't be able to touch the `/cache` this way, as it's not exposed to the computer. And maybe you are dealing with different locations (internal versus external SD card)?

Comment: "Connected via USB" is still a bit unspecific. Does it use *USB Mass Storage*? In that case, it's no longer accessible on your Android device. Done via MTP, it might require a refresh (F5) in Windows Explorer to tell it something has changed. If Explorer caches the remote directory, it might be stupid enough to stick to that cache even after a re-connect; a refresh should do the job in that case as well. Otherwise remember the message: "You moved your mouse pointer. Please reboot for the change to take effect."

Comment: You are just wrong. See my answer, the only solution i found was to reboot Windows. It would be interesting though if there was another solution. I desconnected and reconnected a few times, still the new folder wasn't visible in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Just disconnecting and reconnecting the phone is not enough.

You have to restart Windows. Then the freshly created folders will appear in your filebrowser n Windows too.