# Transfer Files Though USB to PC

Tags: usb, file-transfer, windows

Browsing my android device though USB shows very old files.
Someone else has had this [issue.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/53331/how-do-i-actualize-the-visible-files-in-file-explorer-on-windows-browsing-sdcard)

I do not wish to reboot my PC or phone every time I want to get files from my phone. I also do not like the idea of having to ssh into my phone though usb.

Is there a simple way to transfer files though USB to PC from android?

I have a Moto G on 4.4.2 and my PC is running Windows 7.

Comment: You can use an app like [Servers Ultimate Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.serversultimatepro) to run a file server (say FTP). It's easy. See my answer [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/91900/is-there-a-viable-alternative-to-mtp-for-file-transfer/106323#106323) to know more about the possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files and folder you see via USB (or to be specific through the USB MTP protocol) can be different from the files and folder that are really in the sdcard section on your device.

In my case a lot of files and folders in the sdcard section were invisible via USB. 
After executing the app [Rescan SD Card](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uberullu.rescansd) the files and folders visible via USB were exactly the one that exist on my sdcard section.